# Why is Launchpad laggy when using a scaled resolution?

Tags: mojave, mac-mini, resolution, launchpad, 4k

I bought a 32" 4k display and when I use the 4k resolution on it, everything is too small. This is why I use something in between 2k and 4k, but that resolution is not native apparently, and Launchpad is laggy when using it.

If I swipe left to go to the next page of the Launchpad, the sliding animation is choppy. Is there a way to fix this?

I am using a 2018 Mac mini running macOS Mojave 10.14.5.

Comment: What is the version of macOS Mojave that you are running. What is the make and model of the Mac that you are using?

Comment: @NimeshNeema mac mini 2018 running mojave 10.14.5.

Comment: It would help to know some basic specs of your Mini: Which type of CPU does it have — i3, i5, or i7? And how much system RAM is installed? Do you have _only_ the one display attached? If so, exactly how is the display attached to the Mini — which port on the Mini, which port on the display, and what kind of cable? Precisely what resolution setting have you chosen in the "Displays" panel of System Preferences? (If you have more than one display attached, please provide this info for each display.)

Comment: @jdmc I have a 6 core i5. 32 gigs of RAM. 1 display attached. I tried all kinds of ports, HDMI, thunderbolt 3, displayport (usb-c to dp cable). I have just 1 32 inch 4k display. It doesn't matter what resolution I choose, if it isn't native, it lags. So, it works fine with 1920x1080, 2560x1440 and 3840x2160 (those are non scaled native resolutions). But if I choose 3008x1692 or 3360x1890, it lags, because it needs to scale things. Unfortunately, I can't use native resolutions, because everything is either too small or too large for me.

Comment: At this point I've disabled launchpad animations through terminal altogether, so it's okay. But safari still lags, when you double click a youtube video to enter full screen, for example. That's why I've been using chrome, which works just fine. So, I'm okay overall, but sucks that this can't be fixed.

Comment: Normally, the Mac internally renders the display space at twice the specified resolution, then interpolates that rendering down to 4K, and then sends the resulting 4K signal to the 4K display device. However, you can force the Mac to output video at literally your chosen resolution, leaving it to the 4K display device to interpolate the signal across its actual pixel grid. To do this, open the Displays prefs, hold down the Option key while clicking on "Scaled", tick the "Show low resolution modes" checkbox, and select the version of your desired resolution that's notated as "(low resolution)".

Comment: @jdmc i know that, it sucks, it looks really bad.

Comment: @hey_you: Like you, I also have a 2018 Mac Mini ("MM18") with 6-core i5 processor and 32 GB of RAM. I've had some video problems too, but I run *three* 4K displays simultaneously! And the video problems have gotten much better with successive maintenance releases of Mojave. Make sure you're fully updated; as of today (2019-10-21), the latest build of Mojave is 18G103. (Based on what I've been reading recently about problems with Catalina on MM18s, I would strongly recommend that you **NOT** attempt to "upgrade" to Catalina for the time being.)

Comment: @jdmc too late, I've already upgraded to Catalina, heh :D I regret upgrading, because it seems that Catalina also has sound problems. Sometimes my headphones randomly spit out a very loud short white noise when playing videos. Don't recommend.